# How can i display a textarea dynamically when i click on a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display text area dynamically inside a div when i click on a hyperlink how it can be done. Please help. Thanks..

```
<div class="fright clr7" style="padding-top:10px;"><a href="">Reply</a></div>

<textarea name="motivo" rows="25" cols="50" style="height:100%; display:none; width: 100%" ></textarea>
```

Comment: where is the text area..?

Comment: You can use hide and show in jquery on click of a tag.

Comment: it is on the same page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("div.fright a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).parent("div.fright").find("textarea").length==0)
    $(this).parent("div.fright").append('<textarea name="test" id="test"></textarea>');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/M3JD9/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can do following;

```
$("a").on("click", function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(".fright").find("textarea").length == 0) {
        $(".fright").append('<textarea name="test" id="test"></textarea>');
    }
});
```

Here is a working demo: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BSLjC/1)**

**Edit:**

If you have hidden textarea you can use following;

```
$("a").on("click", function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("textarea[name='motivo']").show();
});
```

Here is a working demo: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BSLjC/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
$('a[href*="Reply"]').click(function(){
  // update this selector
   $('textarea[name='motivo']').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="fright clr7" style="padding-top:10px;"><a class="reply" href="">Reply</a>
<textarea style="display:none;">

</textarea>
</div>
```

and jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('a.reply').click(function(){

$(this).closest('textarea').show();

return false;

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="fright clr7" style="padding-top:10px;" id="text"><a href="javascript:show()">Reply</a></div>

<script>
  function show()
  {
     document.getElementbyId("text").innerHTML="<textarea>anything here</textarea>";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<div class="fright clr7" style="padding-top:10px;"><a href="">Reply</a>
</div>

<textarea name="motivo" rows="25" cols="50" style="height:100%; display:none; width: 100%" ></textarea>
```

JS

```
$("a:contains('Reply')").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault()
   $('textarea[name="motivo"]').show();

});
```

[<kbd>**DEMO**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/7shtd/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this 
i have used jquery

```
<script>
 $("#Test").click(function() {
  $("#TestDiv").html("<textarea rows='4'></textarea>");
 });
</script>


<div class="fright clr7" id="TestDiv" style="padding-top:10px;"><a href="" id="Test">Reply</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<html>`

`<head>`

`<script type="text/javascript">`

`function showtext()`

`{`

`document.getElementById('text_a').style.display = 'block';`

`}`

`</script>`

`</head>`

`<body>`

`<div>`

`<textarea id="text_a" style="display:none;"></textarea>`

`<a href="javascript:showtext();">Show Textarea</a>`

`</div>`

`</body>`

`</html>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**[Working Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6364U/1/)**

```
$('.fright a').click(function() {
    $('.textarea').fadeIn(500);
     return false;
});
```

Good Luck...

Answer (score 0):

You can create textarea on click and append inside DIV, it will be available whenever user click on link.

```
<div class="fright clr7" style="padding-top:10px;"><a href="">Reply</a></div>

$(function(){
      $('.fright').on('click', 'a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      $('<textarea />', {
          cols: 50,
          rows: 25,
          name: 'motivo',
          class: 'motivo-text'
      }).appendTo('.fright');
});
```